# How to change select options based on previous selection in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC to bind a dropdown/select of workflow states.

Example of workflow states are - *Open*, *Scheduled*, *Closed* etc. All these are displayed properly in UI.

Now I have to add a bit different logic so that these state options are dynamic based on current stored state.

For instance, if current workflow state stored is *Scheduled* then user cannot see/select *Open* but just *Closed*.

Similarly, if current workflow state is *Closed* then user should not see/select *Scheduled* but just *Open*.

So, each state has some sort of linked states where user can go next.

Please suggest a way how I can do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For instance, if current workflow state stored is Scheduled then user
> cannot see/select Open but just Closed.
>
> Similarly, if current workflow state is Closed then user should not
> see/select Scheduled but just Open.
>
> So, each state has some sort of linked states where user can go next.

If you just display one record with the workflow state, in the controller, you could use the switch statement to filter the workflow state based on the current state, then use ViewBag or ViewData to transfer the filter state to the view page and bind the select element.

If you are display multiple records with the workflow state, you can create a view model with the dropdownlist select options.

Please refer the following sample, in this sample, when page load, it will filter the state based on the current state, then after change the state, it will use JQuery Ajax to update the DropDownList options:

```
public class WorkFlowState
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SelectedState { get; set; } 
}
public class ArticleViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SelectedState { get; set; }
    public List<WorkFlowState> States { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    private readonly IDataRepository _repository;
    public ArticleController(IDataRepository dataRepository)
    {
        _repository = dataRepository;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //query database to get all article with state.
        var articles = new List<Article>(){
            new Article() { Id = 1, Name = "A", SelectedState = "Open" },
            new Article() { Id = 2, Name = "B", SelectedState = "Scheduled" },
             new Article() { Id = 3, Name = "C", SelectedState = "Closed" },
        };

        //get all states: Open, Scheduled, Closed.
        var allstate = _repository.GetWorkFlowStates();

        //based on the article current state to set the Dropdownlist select items:
        var articlelist = articles.Select(c => new ArticleViewModel()
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Name = c.Name,
            SelectedState = c.SelectedState,
            States =
               c.SelectedState == "Scheduled" ? allstate.Where(d=>d.State != "Open").ToList():
               c.SelectedState == "Closed" ? allstate.Where(d=>d.State !="Scheduled").ToList():
               allstate.ToList()
        }); 
          
        return View(articlelist);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult GetStates(string selectedState)
    {
        //get all states
        var allstate = _repository.GetWorkFlowStates();
        //filter states
        switch (selectedState)
        {
            case "Scheduled":
                allstate = allstate.Where(d => d.State != "Open").ToList();
                break;
            case "Closed":
                allstate = allstate.Where(d => d.State != "Scheduled").ToList();
                break;
        }

        return Json(allstate);
    }
```

View page:

```
@model IEnumerable<Core3_1MVC.Models.ArticleViewModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SelectedState)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <select asp-for="@item.SelectedState" asp-items="@(new SelectList(item.States, "State", "State"))"> 
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>

@section Scripts{ 

<script>  
    $(function () {
        $("select").each(function (index, item) {
            $(item).change(function () {
                var selectedstate = $(this).val();
                var ddl = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Article/GetStates",
                    method: "Post",
                    data: { "selectedState": selectedstate },
                    success: function (result) {
                        ddl.empty(); //clear the options:
                        var s = "";
                        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                            s += '<option value="' + result[i].state + '">' + result[i].state + '</option>';
                        }
                        ddl.html(s);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

The result as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. It gave me a good starting point.

Comment: I tried changing data type of SelectedState from string to WorkFlowState in Article and ArticleViewModel. And updated the controller code. With these changes, when I run my code , the states dropdown populates all the entries but nothing comes selected. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Ah! I changed the view code from SelectedState to SelectedState.State. It works now.